# 2buttons, write a method to change previously clicked button's background image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I have 5 buttons in a form.
i want to every time a button is pressed previous pressed button's background image be changed. for example at first button1 was pressed and now when i click on button3 it should change the button1 background image, please help.
regards

Comment: Sad but C# has no button control, can you fix the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public class ButtonExample 
{
Button prevButton;

button1_click(Object sender,Argument e)
   {

    if(prevButton!=null)
    {
        //Change image here
    }
    prevButton = (Button)sender;
  }
}
```

`button1_Click` is button function for first button.

Assign this method  to all button's click